# real time data plotting line graph with zoom effect in native android

Tags: android, kotlin, graph, android-jetpack-compose

I have a graph with real time data, the issue with that is it is not plotting in equal interval and on zoom it is starching the canvas instead of changing the interval .

Kindly help me by suggesting any 3rd party library for line graph with following feature.

1. real-time value plotting
2. zoom in and out effect with axis value changing in both X and Y axis.
3. show the plot point on the graph line when user touch the line
4. customizable color of the graph

Comment: Removed `android-studio` tag as that tag is for issues/problems with the Android Studio product. This question has nothing to do with the Android Studio product.